# Definir variáveis para chamar uma função

Tags: javascript, ajax, variáveis

Eu estou tentando incluir variáveis para chamar uma função, mas não estou conseguindo

```
function Geral()
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var url="pagina.asp?a=1";
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    { 
    document.getElementById("dados").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    newTag(dados);
    }
}
```

eu fiz assim, mas não deu certo:

```
Geral("pagina.asp?a=1","dados",dados)
function Geral(PAGINA,DADOS,TAG)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var url="PAGINA";
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged(DADOS,TAG);
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(A,B) 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    { 
    document.getElementById(A).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    newTag(B);
    }
}
```

o que está errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se queres chamar a função `stateChanged` com dados "pré-configurados`podes usar o`.bind`. Assim a função não é invocada (que é o que está a acontecer agora) e podes usar esses dados depois.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged.bind(null, DADOS,TAG);
```

e depois usar como tens.

Porem isto tem limitações, uma vez que estás a usar um `xmlHttp` global...

Sugiro mudar a lógica um pouco e fazer algo assim:

```js
function Geral(PAGINA, DADOS, TAG, done) {
  var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
  var url = PAGINA;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) done(DADOS, TAG, xmlHttp.responseText)
  };
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

Geral("pagina.asp?a=1", "dados", dados, function(A, B, res) {
  document.getElementById(A).innerHTML = res;
  newTag(B);
})
```

Comment: muito obrigado, atendeu as minhas necessidades.